# Binary Trie in F#

Tags: functional-programming, f#, integer, bitwise, trie

I have this little exercise writing a binary trie in F#. In C# it can be done in few lines, but here it became more complicated than I had expected (especially the `add` function):

```
open System

type BitTrie = 
    | BitTrie of Zero:BitTrie * One:BitTrie
    | NullTrie

module BitTrie = 

    let ubound = 31  // 32 bits integer

    let add value trie =
        let rec adder shift curTrie = 
            if shift < 0 then curTrie
            else
                match (value >>> shift) &&& 1, curTrie with
                | 0, BitTrie(zero, one) ->
                    match zero with
                    | BitTrie(_) -> BitTrie(adder (shift - 1) zero, one)
                    | NullTrie -> BitTrie(adder (shift - 1) (BitTrie(NullTrie, NullTrie)), one)
                | 1, BitTrie(zero, one) ->
                    match one with
                    | BitTrie(_) -> BitTrie(zero, adder (shift - 1) one)
                    | NullTrie -> BitTrie(zero, adder (shift - 1) (BitTrie(NullTrie, NullTrie)))
                | bit, _ -> raise (InvalidOperationException(sprintf "Invalid bit value: %d" bit))

        adder ubound trie

    let contains value trie =
        let rec searcher shift curTrie =
            if shift < 0 then curTrie <> NullTrie
            else 
                match (value >>> shift) &&& 1, curTrie with
                | _, NullTrie -> false
                | 0, BitTrie(zero, _) -> searcher (shift - 1) zero
                | 1, BitTrie(_, one) -> searcher (shift - 1) one
                | bit, _ -> raise (InvalidOperationException(sprintf "Invalid bit value: %d" bit))
        searcher ubound trie

    let isEmpty trie =
        match trie with
        | NullTrie -> true
        | BitTrie(NullTrie, NullTrie) -> true
        | BitTrie(_) -> false

    let create () = BitTrie(NullTrie, NullTrie)

    let addValues values trie =
        values |> Seq.fold (fun accTrie value -> add value accTrie) trie

    let fromValues values = create() |> addValues values

    let toSeq trie =
        let rec iterator value curTrie =
            seq {
                match curTrie with
                | NullTrie -> ()
                | BitTrie(NullTrie, NullTrie) -> yield value
                | BitTrie(zero, one) -> 
                    yield! (iterator (value <<< 1) zero)
                    yield! (iterator ((value <<< 1) + 1) one)
            }

        iterator 0 trie

    let toList trie = trie |> toSeq |> Seq.toList
    let toArray trie = trie |> toSeq |> Seq.toArray

    let iter action trie = trie |> toSeq |> Seq.iter action
```

I know this pattern match

`bit, _ -> raise (InvalidOperationException(sprintf "Invalid bit value: %d" bit))`

will never happen, but hate to leave the compiler unsatisfied.

---

Here are some test cases:

```
let testBitTrie () =

    let values = [ 0b1011001; 0b1101101; 0b1011011; Int32.MaxValue; (Int32.MaxValue >>> 16) - 1; 0; -1; Int32.MinValue ]
    let trie = values |> BitTrie.fromValues

    trie |> BitTrie.iter (fun v -> printfn "%s -> %d" (Convert.ToString(v, 2)) v)

    printfn ""
    trie 
    |> BitTrie.addValues [ 35; 45 ]
    |> BitTrie.iter (fun v -> printfn "%s -> %d" (Convert.ToString(v, 2)) v)


    //values @ [1; 2; 4; 100] |> Seq.iter (fun v -> printfn "%d: %b" v (trie |> BitTrie.contains (v)))

let solveXorMax () = 
    //let rand = new Random(1);
    //let values = Enumerable.Range(0, 5000).Select(fun x -> rand.Next(rand.Next(0, 10000000))).ToList();
    //let trie = values |> BitTrie.fromValues

    let values = [ 3; 10; 5; 2; 25; 8 ]
    let trie = values |> BitTrie.fromValues

    let folder (max: int) value =
        let rec iter shift xor curTrie : int = 
            if shift <= 0 then Math.Max(max, xor)
            else
                match (value >>> shift) &&& 1, curTrie with
                | 0, BitTrie(zero, one) ->               
                    match zero, one with
                    | _, BitTrie(_) -> iter (shift - 1) (xor + (1 <<< shift)) one
                    | BitTrie(_), _ ->  iter (shift - 1) xor zero
                | 1, BitTrie(zero, one) ->
                    match zero, one with
                    | BitTrie(_), _ -> iter (shift - 1) (xor + (1 <<< shift)) zero
                    | _, BitTrie(_) -> iter (shift - 1) xor one
        iter BitTrie.ubound 0 trie

    let max = values |> Seq.fold folder (Int32.MinValue)
    printfn "%d" max
```

`solveXorMax ()` finds the maximum xor value of two values in the input set - taken from [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221444/leetcode-maximum-xor-of-two-numbers-in-an-array)

I'm interested in any comment, but especially if you can see a smarter/shorter approach for the `add` function. My self-imposed restriction was to use a discriminated union type as data type for the trie node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Big Issue

You have a problem with empty Tries: `toSeq` thinks they contain one element: it returns `seq { 0 }` for an empty Trie.

```
Seq.length (BitTrie.toSeq (BitTrie.create ())) = 1
```

This `0` value then goes away when you add anything. I think `create` should probably be producing a `NullTrie`. There's also no need for it to be a method; I'd prefer an `empty` value, but at that point `you could just rename`NullTrie`to`EmptyTrie`and everyone should be happy. Moving the union into the module would let you just use`Empty` without stepping on any toes.

I can't work out what `NullTrie` is really meant to do otherwise; except produce confusing exceptions: `BitTrie.add 0 NullTrie` will throw your `InvalidOperationException(sprintf "Invalid bit value: %d" bit)`.

I think you can fix this by 'ensuring' `curTrie` is not a `NullTrie`. You can probably use active patterns to resolve this nicely, but I forgot how to use those long ago, so instead I would add an `ensure` (I'm sure you can think of a better name, but it's late and I can't) function...

```
let private ensure trie =
    match trie with
    | Empty -> BitTrie(Empty, Empty)
    | _ -> trie
```

... and then modify the `match` in `add` (which allows us to simplify it somewhat):

```
match (value >>> shift) &&& 1, (ensure curTrie) with
| 0, BitTrie(zero, one) ->
    BitTrie(adder (shift - 1) zero, one)
| 1, BitTrie(zero, one) ->
    BitTrie(zero, adder (shift - 1) one)
| bit, _ -> raise (InvalidOperationException(sprintf "Invalid bit value: %d" bit))
```

But there is still a big problem, because `BitTrie(Empty, Empty)` contains nothing, but apparently isn't empty. This reveals a serious design issue: the meaning of the `Trie` is tied to `ubound` but you can produce 'invalid' Tries, and trivially so. At this point I would give up on the public `BitTrie` DU, and instead implement a self-contained class where I can encapsulate and control everything, providing methods for producing Tries with a valid and meaningful state.

One option you could consider is making `BitTrie` a ternary union, where you have a type indicating whether the value is present or not, so that it is unambigous. This, however, goes funny because you are using a classical Trie for integers. For example, `00000` = `0`, but these sequences would have different positions in a `Trie`. I think your self-impose constraint might need to be relaxed if you want a sound API.

### Other

- Using a variant of the `ensure` method above which returns just a tuple rather than a `BitTrie`, you can remove the need to cover the `empty` case in `add`. Then if you really wanted to get rid of the exception, you could go with `(value >>> shift) &&& 1 > 0` and use `false` and `true` instead of `0` and `1`. The same can be done in `contains`, but looking at it I think it is less clear.
- It seems odd to provide `BitTrie.iter` specifically (as opposed to `map` or `fold` or whatever); I'd be inclined to only provide `toSeq`, and just leave the consumer to call `Seq.iter` themselves.
- As always, I would prefer all public types and functions had inline documentation. `toSeq`, for example, probably wants to document any guarantees you will make about ordering (which presently is based on the bit values, so starts with 0 and ends with -1, which some might think odd).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've read and learned. Your suggestions about `add` and an introduction of a `Bit` DU have removed the complexity from that function. I've also introduced a leaf node - indicating a valid right most bit of a contained number. You may be right about making a class-type implementation - but it was not the objective of this exercise - and besides that I like the DU/module approach. I hope you get a little more up votes...